# How to Line-On-Sides legend of a fieldset?

Tags: html, css, fieldset

I have a fieldset with a legend inside.

```
<fieldset>
   <legend>TEXT</legend>
</fieldset>
```

I'm trying to apply a style and I need the following:

Sample1:

--------------------TEXT------------------------

Sample2:

TEXT------------------------

Ps: line not dashed

Is there a simple way to do that only with css? I found some samples with tables...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?:

```css
#sample1 {
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

#sample2 {
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<fieldset id="sample1">
   <legend>Sample 1</legend>
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="sample2">
   <legend>Sample 2</legend>
</fieldset>
```